# REGEX for non repeating character(Accepting all languages like Spanish, French, German), No space and no comma on start and end

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, angular8, regex-negation

Used in Angular Forms, I have form in UI where I need to add letters,

Code for angular where I am using the regex

```
this.createForm = new FormGroup({
        letters: new FormControl('', [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.pattern('/^(?!.*(\p{L}).*?\1)\p{L}(?:,\p{L})*$/u')
            ]),
});
```

However it should not contain repeat characters and leading trailing commas and No Spaces.
Explanation:

I need regex which will not allow

1. Space
2. Leading Trailing Commas
3. Repeat Characters.

For Example:

A,B,C,A - Not Acceptable

A, B,C,D - Not Acceptable

A,B,C,D, - Not Acceptable

,A,B,C,D - Not Acceptable

Á,B,Á - Not Acceptable

A,E,I,O,U,Y,À,È,Ù,É,Â,Ê,Î,Ô,Û,Ë,Ï,Ü,Ÿ,Æ,Œ,Ç  - Should be accepted

A,E,U,O,I,Ä,Ü - Should be Accepted

Á,Â,Ã,Ú,Í,E,Ê,É,Ó,Ô,O - Should be accepted

Currently I have one Regex which was answered, but only works for English Characters

`^(?:([A-Z])(?!.*?\1),?\b)+$`

I tried below regex , but it is not working.

`^(?:([A-ZàèìòùÀÈÌÒÙáéíóúýÁÉÍÓÚÝâêîôûÂÊÎÔÛãñõÃÑÕäëïöüÿÄËÏÖÜŸçÇßØøÅåÆæŒœ])(?!.*?\1),?\b)+$`

`^(?:([\p{L}])(?!.*?\1),?\b)+$`

I might be wrong about the above regex, as I am new to Regex,

Can anyone help me with a Regex which can work for other languages as well.

Thank you.

Comment: If `\p{L}` works then you can use `^(?!.*([\p{L}]).*\1)[\p{L}]+(?:,*[\p{L}]+)*$` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cozwvP/1)

Comment: It would be great if you added the code you are using the regex in.

Comment: I have updated the code where I need to use this regex

Answer (score 2):

Your regex is very close, just need a small modification:

```
^(?:([\p{L}])(?!.*?\1)(?:,(?!$)|$))+$
```

There are no word boundaries between a comma and a non-alphanumeric character(`ÀÈÌÒÙ` etc.). So your regex didn't work.

Instead you can test `(?:,(?!$)|$)` for separators: **a comma that not followed by the end of a string** or **the end of a string**.

See the test cases [here](https://regex101.com/r/9iNQL6/1).

Comment: Hi @Hao Wu,  I am unable to figure how to get this regex working in Angular file, I have updated the question with a code where I am using, 

I tried escaping the backslash by adding 1 more backslash or forward slash, However still it is not working, Can you please help.?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use

```js
/^(?!.*(\p{L}).*?\1)\p{L}(?:,\p{L})*$/u
```

A bit faster version since the comma-separated letter pattern is easier to check for first:

```js
/^(?=\p{L}(?:,\p{L})*$)(?!.*(\p{L}).*?\1).*/u
```

See the [regex demo #1](https://regex101.com/r/dSBNbj/1) and [regex demo #2](https://regex101.com/r/dSBNbj/3).

Here, there is **no need to check for word boundaries**, boundaries are set with anchors and the `x(,x)*`-like pattern.

Mind the `u` flag, too, you need a regex notation to make this regex work at all, so be careful when using this in your code.

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!.*(\p{L}).*?\1)` - no repeated letter anywhere in the string
- `\p{L}` - a letter
- `(?:,\p{L})*` - zero or more repetitions of a comma and a letter
- `$` - till the end of string.

In your code, use

```js
this.createForm = new FormGroup({
        letters: new FormControl('', [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.pattern(/^(?!.*(\p{L}).*?\1)\p{L}(?:,\p{L})*$/u)
            ]),
});
```

Comment: Hi @Wiktor, Your code is working, However I am unable to figure how to get that worked in Angular file, I have added the code where I am using, 

I tried escaping the backslash by adding 1 more backslash or forward slash, However still it is not working, Can you please help.?

Comment: @Nitesh See the updated answer. You had extra quotes.